# Clear UV seams not clearing seams

Tags: modeling, uv, import

I want to clear UV seams on a object and remake them myself, but neither *UV Mapping > Clear Seams* nor *UV Mapping > Reset Seems* to work. Please see attachment images.

This is my mesh before i do *UV Mapping > Clear Seams*:

[image: Before clearing seams]

This is my mesh after I did *UV Mapping > Clear Seams*. Seams still present:

[image: After clear seams]

How do I fix this problem? I can't clearly cut my mesh while those seams are around.

Here is the scene:

[image]

*I think this model was originally created in 3Ds Max.*

Comment: did you select the whole mesh in edit mode, then CTRL + E --> Clear seam?

Comment: Yes, i did it just as you said gladys, seams are still present.

Comment: can you upload the blend model?

Comment: Uploaded it, link in the main post.

Comment: i downloaded your model but I didn't see seams, I saw only edges that are marked as sharp so the only thing you have to do to clear those CTRL + E --> Clear sharp.

Comment: You are right gladys. I was being an idiot, i never ever knew about this feature. I thought those are UV seams. Should you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There were no seams in the model the edges were marked as sharp so the only thing you have to do to clear those <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>E</kbd> *> Clear Sharp*.

Answer (score 2):

This problem seems to appear more often when importing from another platform into Blender. I imported a mesh I made in Blender version 2.49 into Blender 2.68A, and had a similar problem: I had what appeared to be seams that would not clear with the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>E</kbd> shortcut. The solution was to use <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, and set the value of the crease to  -1 on the numeric keypad.

Comment: Thanks for contribution brasshat, gladys found the solution. Those was not UV seams, it was sharp edges.

Comment: IvanKartofanov, when I started my answer I did not yet see your edit, nor the blend file. And yes, I agree that @gladys should change her comment to an answer. But I think my answer is enough different from hers to be desirable for completeness, particularly since more than on entity--seams, creases, &c. seem to have the same inconsistencies, especially between meshes created with pre-2.5 versions imported into post-2.5 UI.